# Parameterizations of the unit simplex in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, simplex

The unit simplex in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is

$$\Delta^3 = \left\{(t_1,t_2,t_3)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}\mid t_1+t_2+t_3 = 1 \mbox{ and } t_i \ge 0 \mbox{ for all } i\right\}$$
When trying to describe it parametrically, an obvious choice is
$$ (x,y,1-x-y)$$
over an approriate two-dimensional domain. This particular parameterization is not symmetric, as the third coordinate plays a different role than the first two.

Are there any other parameterizations of the unit simplex $\Delta^3$ which are more natural? For example, ones in which the distance to the edge can be easily read. If so, I would appreciate some examples. Thank you!

Comment: You could first transform to barycentric coordinates and then use the parameterization you mention

Answer (score 6):

Take

$$\begin{aligned}
t_1 &= \sin^2\theta\cos^2\phi \\
t_2 &= \sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi \\
t_3 &= \cos^2\theta
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: There is a "Math Processing Error", seems something's wrong with the latex. I fixed it.

Comment: How do you generalize this to the unit $n$-simplex in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$?

Comment: @becko These coordinates are the squares of the usual spherical coordinates. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates

Comment: @Adam So for the unit $n$-simplex, just square the $n$-spherical coordinates. Thanks!

Comment: The coordinate $t_3$ still plays a role different than the others...